# Aligning a child div's right/bottom in parent

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, right-align

It's item form with elements/divs (checkbox groups, text field, dropdowns). elements coming one by one. If user initial(select or input value) current element is validated and added to wrapper container.
Html example is bellow:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <!-- more divs -->
</div>
```

My problem:

- child div has more complex
- order is unchangeable
- the size of div is dynamnic, between 1-20
- column count 4 is just for example in reality is depend on wrapper div width, between 1-8
- no javascript usage

Mission: like a pic
[image: div bottom/right]

Comment: hello mr. ts.tsgoo, which style apply on for this html code, put in your question so i give you proper answer.

Comment: Please add complete code that can be helpful in understanding where the problem is. Like in your case how can anyone know what styling are you using.

Comment: What did you do to achieve this? What problem did you face? Or you're just looking for someone who will code for you for free?

Answer (score 1):

if you have a fixed number of div and display like above

so following code will help you

```css
#wrapper div{
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
     float: right;
     margin: 5px;
     padding: 30px;
     font-weight: bold;
     font-size: xx-large;
 }

 #wrapper
 {
  border: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
 }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    
    <div>2</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div style="clear: right;">6</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: the order of child div is unchangeable for me

Comment: you can tell me your output clearly which type of output you need

Comment: Apologies for my bad structured question Bhargav, Thank you for your Help

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by using a bit of JavaScript and CSS-flex.

```
function reverse(elem){
  for (var i=0; i < elem.childNodes.length; i++) 
    elem.insertBefore(elem.childNodes[i], elem.firstChild);

}
reverse(document.getElementById('wrapper'))
```

```
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
  align-content: flex-start;
  direction: rtl;
}
```

See it in action:

```js
function reverse(elem){
  for (var i=0; i < elem.childNodes.length; i++) 
    elem.insertBefore(elem.childNodes[i], elem.firstChild);

}
reverse(document.getElementById('wrapper'))
```

```css
#wrapper {
  /* the important bit */
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
  align-content: flex-start;
  direction: rtl;
  
  /* styling */
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

#wrapper div {
  /* styling */
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
</div>
```

## Improvement

The JavaScript only reverses the order of the elements. If you add the children yourself, than add them in the reverse and omit the JavaScript.
This would look much nicer and like this:

```css
#wrapper {
  /* the important bit */
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
  align-content: flex-start;
  direction: rtl;
  
  /* styling */
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

#wrapper div {
  /* styling */
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div>6</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>1</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `float` and `transform` like this:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#wrapper {
  transform:rotate(180deg); /* Rotate container 180 degree */
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#wrapper > div {
  transform:rotate(180deg); /* Rotate item 180 degree to display normal */
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  height: 80px; 
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div>7</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>1</div>
</div>
```

But the order is reversed. So if you have more items, just add them into the beginning of container.

If you don't want to use `float`, can use `display: flex` to container:

```
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
align-content: flex-start;
```